# Can I have two functions with same name but different parameters in kotlin interface

Tags: kotlin, interface, overloading

I have an interface with one function and class A implements the function in it.

```kotlin
interface DisplayDetailsBuilder{
    fun buildDetails(name: String, bookResponse: Book, authorName: String): Display
}
```

Now I have another implementing class B where I need another parameter in this function: `displayResponse: DisplayResponse`

```kotlin
fun buildDetails(name:String, bookResponse:Book, authorName:String, displayResponse:DisplayResponse):Display
```

So I want to overload the above interface with following method. So that I don't have to touch existing implementation. so both the class A and B can have their own implementations. But its complaining to implement both functions in KOTLIN> How to achieve it?

I tried to over load the interface but both classes are complaining to implement all members.
Is it possible to achieve this in Kotlin?

If not what's the solution? Should I create another interface?

Comment: Why do you use that interface in the first place? Creating another interface might make sense, but if you intended for both A and B to implement the same interface and be used interchangeably you'll have a problem. Maybe you have a conceptual problem, maybe A is ok to receive an unnecessary parameter and you can just add it to the interface method. It really depends a lot on what those things are, and why you're using this abstraction in the first place